# gae Runtime MCycles

Tags: google-app-engine

GAE dashboard shows stats for different URIs of your app. It includes Req/Min, Requests, Runtime MCycles, and Avg Latency. 
The help provided seems to be outdated, here what it states:

The current load table provides two data points for CPU usage, "Avg CPU (API)" and "% CPU". The "Avg CPU (API)" displays the average amount of CPU a request to that URI has consumed over the past hour, measured in megacycles. The "% CPU" column shows the percentage of CPU that URI has consumed since midnight PST with respect to the other URIs in your application.

1. So I assume Runtime MCycles is what the help calls Avg CPU (API)? 
   How do I map this number to the request stats in the logs?
   For example one of the requests has this kind of logs: `ms=583 cpu_ms=519 api_cpu_ms=402`.
2. Do I understand correctly that ms includes `cpu_ms` and `cpu_ms` includes `api_cpu_ms`?
3. So then `cpu_ms` is the Runtime MCycles which is shown as average for the given URI on dashboard?
4. I have a F1 instance with 600Mhz and concurrency enabled for my app. Does it mean this instance throughput it 600 MCycles per second? So if average request takes 100 Mcycles, it should handle 5-6 request on average?

I am digging into this to try to predict the costs for my app under load.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post (by Nick Johnson) is a useful summary of what the request log fields mean: http://blog.notdot.net/2011/06/Demystifying-the-App-Engine-request-logs

Comment: That link also does not explain the stats on the dashboard, only within the logs.